# Create virtual RDP session using Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, remote-desktop

On Windows 10, I want to run an OpenGL application via Remote Desktop.  This limitation is well-known for Nvidia GeForce cards, and the workaround is to use a BAT script to transfer the session to the console before launching the app like this:

```
tscon 1 /dest:console
start “myapp.exe”
```

This disconnects the RDP session, then the user must reconnect.  I am trying to think of a way to do this while leaving the user connected.  I think it could work like this:

- Create "virtual" RDP session #2
- Connect session 2 to current session 1
- Connect session 1 to console (session 0)
- Launch application in console
- Connect console to session 2
- Kill session 1

Is this possible?  I can't find any commands for creating a virtual session.

Answer (score 0):

New in Windows 10/Server 2016, you actually can do DX11/OpenGL3+ over RDP with a [local group policy change:](https://community.esri.com/thread/225251-enabling-gpu-rendering-on-windows-server-2016-windows-10-rdp)

> - Open the Edit Group Policy tool from Control Panel or use the Windows Search dialog (Windows Key + R, then type in gpedit.msc)
> - Browse to: Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote
>     Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session
>     Environment
> - Then enable “Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions”

There are some other GP settings in there for playing with codecs and the like as well.

If that won't work for you, I'll warn that windows 10 only allows 1 RDP session by default, and I don't think you can have two sessions running as the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Look at installing the pstools PsExec, it will let you start applications interactively in any available session.

You have to specify a user (and password) otherwise it will just display a black window but PsExec also has the option to run the application as system, which doesn't require a password and displays correctly.  But look into the downside of running interactive applications as system, before doing so as it can be a giant security hole.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec